# Spring share @Cachable and @CachePut key

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cache

I'm trying to integrate Spring cache within my project. I've set up a Redis cache manager and it indeed works. However, this is my scenario: I have a `Setting` entity. I want to make a `findAll` method that can return all of the settings and a `setSetting` which allows to set a specific setting.

This is the code I've defined for `getSettings` and `setSetting`:

```
  @Cacheable(value = "setting")
  public List<Setting> getSettings() {
    return repository.findAll();
  }

  @CachePut("setting")
  public Optional<Setting> setSetting(String key, Object value) {
    var setting = this.repository.findByIdentifier(key);
    if (setting.isEmpty()) {
      return Optional.empty();
    }

    try {
      setting.get().setValue(mapper.writeValueAsString(value));
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
      LOG.error("Could not serialize the value: {}", value);
      return Optional.empty();
    }

    this.repository.save(setting.get());
    return setting;
  }
```

When I call to `getSettings` I get a `setting::SimpleKey []` key in my Redis (that's my expected behaviour). However, when I call to `setSetting`, because of the extra argument, instead of overrding the `setting::SimpleKey []` key, I end up with another key in Redis: `"setting::SimpleKey [name, foobar]" (where name and foobar are the arguments I've sent to` setSetting`).

I understand that it's how `kecusyGenerator` works, but it seems quite unexpected and I quite don't understand how to set the original key I've used in `findAll`. Do I **have** to make a custom key generator?

I'll appriciate any help!

Comment: I was wondering why I got two different keys, very well explained, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for `setSetting` to override the cached value returned from `getSettings` both methods should return the `List<Setting>`. You do need to evict the existing cached values before each update of setting e.g.

```
@Cacheable(value = "setting")
public List<Setting> getSettings() {
  return repository.findAll();
}

@CacheEvict(value = "setting", allEntries = true, beforeInvocation = true)
@Cacheable(value = "setting", key = "T(org.springframework.cache.interceptor.SimpleKey).EMPTY")
public List<Setting> setSetting(String key, Object value) {
  // 1. update the setting value (as already done in your code) and save changes
  ...
  this.repository.save(setting.get());

  // 2. Return the list of settings
  return repository.findAll();
}
```